# Render WriteableBitmap in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, bitmap

I have noticed a bizzare situation - in SIlverlight, when a picture is rendered using WriteableBitmap Render method, the resulting pic is very sharp. Of course in WPF Render method is not available. I have used DrawingGroup to render two images on top of each other (I have got a png with transparency and standard JPEG). However in that case the resulting bitmap is not so sharp (especially in case of text).

Could you see any reasons for that? Have you faced such a problem?

Any ideas for the solution?

I need to 'put' a png with transparency on jpeg image and get a precise resulting pic.

Thank you in advance for the replies!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried BitmapScalingMode on RenderOptions? It's an attached property that applies to most DependencyObjects that have anything to do with drawing images. An example:

```
<object Name="myObject" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" .../>
```

or to do this in codebehind:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myObject, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
```